# Error Messages When Trying to use Filter with Swift 4, IOS 11

Tags: ios, arrays, string, struct, swift4

For some reason, when I try and implement the following code, I keep getting either the error that `instance of categoryString can’t be used in MyTableViewController` or (when I tried to use `.contains` instead of `.range` which isn't working either) `the function contains doesn’t exist in the VintageThings struct`.

I know I’m probably missing one dot or something, but I can’t tell where it should be. Please please help.

```
class MyTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // Category is being called from the scene before    
    var categoryString = String()

    var newArray:[VintageThings] = []

    newArray = oldArray.filter({($0.category.range(of: categoryString)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `Array.filter` expects a boolean condition on which it will filter the objects. While in your case your condition i.e `$0.category.range(of: categoryString)` returns  `Range<String.Index>?` as a result. For example in your case to make the condition boolean you will have to check if its range is nil i.e

```
newArray = oldArray.filter( { $0.category.range(of: categoryString) != nil } )
```

OR

```
newArray = oldArray.filter{ $0.category.range(of: categoryString) != nil }
```

OR

```
newArray = oldArray.filter { (vintageThing) -> Bool in
            return vintageThing.category.range(of: categoryString) != nil
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me, I'm still getting an error saying "Instance member 'categoryString' cannot be used on type 'MyTableViewController'. What can I do please?

Comment: You are getting this error because you are assigning values in class scope instead you should only be declaring and/or initializing them as SELF is not available at the time of property initializations. 
however you can use computational getters in swift to achieve what you are trying to. i.e

 `var newArray: [VintageThings] { 
        oldArray.filter{ $0.category.range(of: categoryString) != nil }
}`

Comment: I'm now getting an error saying `Missing return in a function expected to return '[VintageThings]'` and a warning saying `Result of call to 'filter' is unused`. Swift is such a weird language.

Comment: Sorry. I missed the return. it isn't the language's fault. Try this
`var newArray: [VintageThings] { return oldArray.filter{ $0.category.range(of: categoryString) != nil } }`

Comment: Thank you so much Umair, you're a genius and it's working brilliantly. May I ask another question please? What would be the best way of selecting items from the newArray and putting them into an empty array please? Thanks in advance, Lilly.

Comment: `Array.filter` in swift does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The braces and parentheses are unbalanced and you have to check for `!= nil` to get the expected `Bool` result.

```
newArray = oldArray.filter{ $0.category.range(of: categoryString) != nil }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me, I'm still getting an error saying "Instance member 'categoryString' cannot be used on type 'MyTableViewController'. What can I do please?

Comment: The error says that you are calling `categoryString` on the type somewhere else (`MyTableViewController.categoryString`) which cannot work because it's an instance